# How to get minimax algorithm to return the correct move?

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax

I see that this has been asked before but I'm still stuck. I've used a wrapper class as suggested in another answer but the move gets over ridden every time the algorithm finds a "better" node even if it is not a move that max makes but rather min.

```
 private int alphaBetaSearch(Node currentNode, int depth,int alpha,int beta, boolean maxPlayer){

    if (depth == 0){

        return bestValue = currentNode.getValue();
    }

    if(maxPlayer){

        bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(Node child:currentNode.getChildren()){
            bestValue = Integer.max(bestValue, alphaBetaSearch(child, depth-1, alpha, beta, false));
            currentNode.setValue(bestValue);
            alpha = Integer.max(alpha, bestValue);

            if(beta<= alpha) 
                break;

        }
        return bestValue;
    }

    else{

        bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(Node child:currentNode.getChildren()){
            bestValue = Integer.min(bestValue, alphaBetaSearch(child, depth-1, alpha, beta, true));
            currentNode.setValue(bestValue);
            beta = Integer.min(beta, bestValue);

            if (beta<=alpha) 
                break;

        }
        return bestValue;
    }

}
```

Any optimizations or corrections would also be appreciated. Thanks!
Also sorry for the genSuccessors() function. I know the boolean argument doesn't make sense but trust me it works.

Comment: I don't understand. If you call it with an odd depth value, the move set at depth zero *will* be for the opposite player.

Comment: Also, the `.getParent().getParent()==null` guard looks fishy, like you're only setting the move at depths of exactly 2, regardless of what is passed as `depth`?

Comment: Hey @Jeff I figured it out. The edited code shows all the changes in case you were interested. Basically I misunderstood the concept of the minimax algorithm, but also my nodes were structured so that the parent didn't know its children. Now the root can just shuffle through the children to find which has the largest value.

Comment: By editing in the corrected code, you make the question no longer match your problem. Please restore the "bad" code in the question, and instead do a self-answer that contains the corrected code. TIA.